# rendering an image from a rails css file for wicked PDF

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

A cascading nesting of objects is identified via an image relative to the level of nesting:

```
#nestedlist, #nestedlist li {
  font-size: 12px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#nestedlist ul  {
  list-style-image: url("/yellow_dark.png"); 
} 
/* UL Layer # Rules based on quantity_of_ul */
#nestedlist ul ul  {
  list-style-image: url("red_base.png"); 
}
#nestedlist ul ul ul {
  list-style-image: url("/green_light.png");
}
```

etc.

this renders properly in the browser, notwithstanding the location of the image, in the public directory or in the assets directory. However wicked PDF requires an absolute path for images and cannot handle the above; it will return a blank if `list-style-type: none;` or a black bullet if that is not specified. *attempted* to use `list-type: square;`  but that, alas, does not take colour options.

How could a css file be cast to provide absolute urls for images in a precompiled css file invoked by the `pdf`layout for wicked_pdf?

Comment: Copy the base css file to a wicked_pdf version and replace url(" with url(your_absolute_path

Comment: Yes, I could do that with and external static source.  I guess I should've specified that the goal would be to serve it from the application's, either public or assets, directory, thus using a rails command; I am just unclear as to the syntex to render properly in the css file.

Comment: can generate the css dynamically, but in any case, the css url takes absolute file references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure [`asset_host`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-asset-host), because, when it is not specificly set wickedpdf will use local `file://` urls, which didn't work for me:

```rb
if pathname =~ URI_REGEXP
  # asset_path returns an absolute URL using asset_host if asset_host is set
  pathname
else
  File.join(Rails.public_path, asset.sub(/\A#{Rails.application.config.action_controller.relative_url_root}/, ''))
end
```

*https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/2.6.3/lib/wicked_pdf/wicked_pdf_helper/assets.rb#L131*

---

```rb
# config/environment/development.rb

config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"
```

```css
/* app/assets/stylesheets/pdf.css */

ul {
  list-style-image: url("circle.svg");
}
```

```html
<!-- show.pdf.erb -->

<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "pdf" %>

<ul>
  <li>Peaches</li>
  <li>Apples</li>
  <li>Plums</li>
</ul>
```

`wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag` helper now outputs this:

```html
<style type='text/css'>
ul {
  list-style-image: url(http://localhost:3000/assets/circle-a438dbaaf222a262201c1d46bd32e81d2ecb96f95fd50d00a5ad9b57a7778248.svg);
}
</style>
```

[image: pdf]

---

You could also try using `asset_url("circle.svg")` explicitly to get a full url or `wicked_pdf_asset_base64("circle.svg")` to inline a data url.